# SQL select results from multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql, forms, join, select

I have made a search form which is showing results successfully from 1 table "links", but I want the results to be searched from multiple tables like "links1" "links2".

This is my coding

```
$orderby = " ORDER BY id desc"; 
$sql = "SELECT * FROM links " . $queryCondition;
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
```

Comment: UNION all SELECT's this will only work, if you have the same number of columns

Comment: You could use a `union` and `select` from each table independently. This isn't really a PHP question, and PHP provided is irrelevant to issue. If you really have tables that are enumerated you likely should not do that. That is a sign of a bad schema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a perfect problem for that `UNION SELECT` can solve. Say you have two tables, `links1` and `links2`, both with the exact same column names. What you can do in SQL then is `SELECT * FROM links1 UNION SELECT * FROM links2` and that will return the data as if both tables were beneath each other. For more info read https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp

Comment: Okay, I will do that from now on. However, I find something like w3schools easier to understand when I don't know something that the primary source